# groupby Not working with laravel and PostreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am using PostreSQL . when I try to use groupBy in my laravel query. It showing **Grouping error:**

```
$available_Area = DB::table('area AS a')
->select('a.*','a.name as a_name', 'f.name as f_name', 'zc.code as zc_code') 
->join('transaction AS t', 't.f_id', '=', 'a.f_id')
->leftjoin('facility AS f', 'f.id', '=', 't.f_id')
->leftJoin('transaction_detail AS td', 'td.t_id', '=', 't.id')
->leftJoin('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id') 
->whereNotIn('a.id', DB::table('transaction_detail AS td')
            ->select('zc.a_id')
            ->join('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id')                  
            ->whereIn('td.card_type', ['C_OVA','C_M21'])
                            ->where('td.t_id', $url)
                        )
            ->groupBy('a.id')
->where('t.id', @$url) 
->get();
```

Then I tried with **DISTINCT ON** It showing syntax error

```
$available_Area = DB::table('area AS a')
->select('a.*','a.name as a_name', 'f.name as f_name', 'zc.code as zc_code', DB::raw("DISTINCT ON(a.id)")) 
->join('transaction AS t', 't.f_id', '=', 'a.f_id')
->leftjoin('facility AS f', 'f.id', '=', 't.f_id')
->leftJoin('transaction_detail AS td', 'td.t_id', '=', 't.id')
->leftJoin('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id') 
->whereNotIn('a.id', DB::table('transaction_detail AS td')
            ->select('zc.a_id')
            ->join('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id')                  
            ->whereIn('td.card_type', ['C_OVA','C_M21'])
                            ->where('td.t_id', $url)
                        )
->where('t.id', @$url) 
->get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821421/why-to-use-dbraw-inside-dbselect-in-laravel this may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `select a.*`, so you should to add all fields into group by statement or apply aggregation function. For example fields  `a.id`, `a.name`, `f.name` added to group by and applied min function on field `zc.code`:

```
$available_Area = DB::table('area AS a')
    ->select('a.id','a.name as a_name', 'f.name as f_name', 'min(zc.code) as zc_code') 
    ->join('transaction AS t', 't.f_id', '=', 'a.f_id')
    ->leftjoin('facility AS f', 'f.id', '=', 't.f_id')
    ->leftJoin('transaction_detail AS td', 'td.t_id', '=', 't.id')
    ->leftJoin('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id') 
    ->whereNotIn('a.id', 
        DB::table('transaction_detail AS td')
            ->select('zc.a_id')
            ->join('zone_component AS zc', 'zc.id', '=', 'td.comp_id')                  
            ->whereIn('td.card_type', ['C_OVA','C_M21'])
            ->where('td.t_id', $url)
    )
    ->groupBy('a.id', 'a.name', 'f.name')
    ->where('t.id', @$url) 
    ->get();
```

[Some simplified example](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/1d7f2d768ebdea0d11afda8b43066aed/php/php8/390a8b1533ba9b4ca6e4a7034aae13ea/)